# Laravel Lighthouse get parsed request

Tags: graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm new to Php Lighthouse and GraphQL in general.

I'm trying to move an older system written in rest api, to GraphQL.In this older system I use the url to get some stuff done conditionally, for instance if the url starts with `/products` I load the e-commerce plugin and if it doesn't I don't load it so it's always fast and optimal.

I know that GraphQL has only one endpoint so I can't do this directly here, so I need a way to still be able to activate and deactivate the plugins on each request dynamically.

I thought if I could get a parsed version of the request. for example for:

```
{
  users{
    data{
      ID,
      display_name
    }
  }
}
```

If I could somehow get the `users` then I could load the plugins which are needed for that.

Yet all I could find was:

https://lighthouse-php.com/5/concepts/request-lifecycle.html#request-parsing

Which basically explains that the parsing occurs according to an standard, but doesn't state how we can access the parsed data.

I need some guidance here, if you have a better way than mine I'm totally open to it and it is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the Visitor. It is an inspection tool from php-graphql. There is an example of this implementation that you can check in Nuwave\Lighthouse\CacheControl:CacheControlServiceProvider.php.

I believe the only thing that you need is to add this to your boot function in the service provider:

```
public function boot(Dispatcher $dispatcher): void
    {
        $dispatcher->listen(
            StartExecution::class,
            function (StartExecution $startExecution) {
                $typeInfo = new TypeInfo($startExecution->schema);

                Visitor::visit($startExecution->query, Visitor::visitWithTypeInfo($typeInfo, [
                    NodeKind::FIELD => function (FieldNode $_) use ($typeInfo): void {
                        $field = $typeInfo->getFieldDef();
                        
                        // @phpstan-ignore-next-line can be null, remove ignore with graphql-php 15
                        if (null === $field) {
                            return;
                        }
                        
                        if ($field->name === 'user') {
                            echo 'enable the plugin';
                        }
                    },
                ]));
            }
        );
    }
```

You can also check the [events](https://lighthouse-php.com/5/api-reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) page, maybe you find a better place to hook into the lifecycle and get the data you need without Visitor.

Comment: It worked very well thank you! You might want to mention that your code goes into a service provider for future visitors.